# Multiple has_many :through and distinct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I know how to use -> { distinct } to get unique relations of a many-to-many relationship.

In my case I have to has_many relations and want to use -> { distinct } on the last one:

```
has_many :group_provider_pivots
has_many :groups, through: :group_provider_pivots, dependent: :destroy
has_many :agencies, -> { distinct }, through: :groups
```

This gives me an error:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...roup_provider_pivots"."provider_id" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(agen...
```

In the code:

```
<% @agencies.each do |agency| %>
```

When I remove the distinct part everything works but I don't get unique agencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate uniqueness one of your model attribute with scope with the relation. For example if you had a attribute that is called `name` in your model you can get distinct agencies by validate like this

```
validates :name, , uniqueness: { scope: :agencies }
```

by doing that you ensure that every model instance has a unique set of agencies.